# Question about Cake Pattern

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, dao

Let there a few separate DAO classes `OrderDAO`, `ProductDAO`, and `CustomerDAO` that store/retrieve data in the database and share a single instance `DataSource` (the database connection factory).

In order to create a `DataSource` instance and plug it in `DAOs` we usually use Spring DI. Now I would like to do that in Scala without any DI framework.

I've read about the [cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-scala-dependency-injection-di.html), and it looks like I should do the following:

```
trait DatabaseContext { val dataSource:Datasource }

trait OrderDAO {this:DatabaseContext =>
  ... // use dataSource of DatabaseContext
}

trait ProductDAO {this:DatabaseContext => 
  ... // use dataSource of DatabaseContext
}

object DAOImpl extends OrderDAO with ProductDAO with DatabaseContext {
  val dataSource = ... // init the data source
}
```

Do I understand the cake pattern correctly?

Can I implement these `DAOs` differently using the cake pattern ?

What does it provide that DI frameworks like Spring do not ?

How can I create separate `OrderDAOImpl` and `ProductDAOImpl` objects sharing the same `DataSource` instance instead of one big `DAOImpl`?

Comment: I briefly read about the cake pattern and didn't see what the excitement was about either. It seems a lot more complicated than existing DI containers.

Comment: Whether you like it or not isn't really relevant to the question. And "am I missing something" is a very weak question. Perhaps it would be better to ask "what does this provides that X doesn't?", which is a clear question.

Comment: @Daniel. Thanks. I have rephrased the question.

Answer (score 5):

The advantages of the cake pattern are:

- Unlike configuration-file-based DI solutions, matching contracts to
  implementations is done at compile time, which reduces class-finding
  and compatibility issues. However, many DI engines have an
  alternative in-code configuration feature
- No third-party libraries
  are used. Self-type annotations which let you use the pattern are a
  native language feature. No special syntax is used to retrieve the
  implementation of the contract
- Forgetting to specify an
  implementation for a component needed by another component results in
  a runtime error - just check this article
  http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di.html
  and try not specifying one of the components or specifying a
  trait instead of a concrete class in any of the cake pattern
  examples or even forgetting to initialize a val corresponding to a component needed

However, to experience these advantages, you need to more strictly adhere to the architecture of the pattern - check the same article and note the wrapping traits that contain the actual contracts and implementations.

Your examples do not seem to be strictly the cake pattern. In your case you could've just used inheritance to create implementations for your traits and use separate classes for each DAO component. In the cake pattern the consuming code would be a component just like the DAO code, and the code assembling the dependencies together would stand alone from it.

To illustrate the cake pattern, you would have to add consuming classes (domain layer or UI layer) to your example. Or it the case your DAO components accessed each other's features you could illustrate the cake pattern on you DAO alone.

to make it short,

```
trait OrderDAOComponent {
    val dao: OrderDAO
    trait OrderDAO {  
        def create: Order
        def delete(id: Int): Unit  
        //etc 
    }  
}

trait OrderDAOComponentImpl extends OrderDAOComponent {  
    class OrderDAOJDBCImpl extends OrderDAO {  
        def create: Order = {/*JDBC-related code here*/}
        def delete(id: Int) {/*JDBC-related code here*/}
        //etc
    }  
}  

//This one has a dependency
trait OrderWebUIComponentImpl {  
    this: OrderDAOComponent =>  
    class OrderWebUI {  
        def ajaxDelete(request:HttpRequest) = {  
            val id = request.params("id").toInt
            try {
                dao.delete(id)
                200
            }
            catch {
                case _ => 500
            }

        }  
    }  
}  

//This matches contracts to implementations

object ComponentRegistry extends  
    OrderDAOComponentImpl with  
    OrderWebUIComponentImpl
{  
    val dao = new OrderDAOJDBCImpl
    val ui = new OrderWebUI
}  

//from some front-end code
val status = ComponentRegistry.ui.ajaxDelete(request)
```

More on your example. I think it could be more like cake if:

```
trait DatabaseContext { val dataSource:Datasource }

trait OrderDAOComponent {this:DatabaseContext =>
    trait OrderDAOImpl {
        ... // use dataSource of DatabaseContext
    }
}

trait ProductDAOComponent {this:DatabaseContext => 
    trait ProductDAOImpl {
        ... // use dataSource of DatabaseContext
    }
}

object Registry extends OrderDAOComponent with ProductDAOComponent with DatabaseContextImpl {
    val dataSource = new DatasourceImpl //if Datasource is a custom trait, otherwise wrapping needed
    val orderDAO = new OrderDAOImpl
    val productDAO = new ProductDAOImpl
}

//now you may use them separately
Registry.orderDAO.//
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

- Statically checked at compile time.